# Wcf service with Console Application

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, console

I am trying to Wcf Service in Console Application. Insert, update and delete operation is working by wcf service with console application but i am unable to retrieve data from database by using wcf service in Console Application. I have local class which have the required data members and i defined a method inside wcf service which expect a parameter called account number. In the console application user enter the account number and based on this account the console should retrieve all data from sql database but its only retrieve account number which I provide when I run Console Application  . If anyone help me on I will be grateful.

Here is the code for local class..

```
      [DataContract]
         public class AccountBalanceRequest : Current_Account_Details
            {
    string account_number;

    [DataMember]
    public string Account_Number
    {
        get { return account_number; }
        set { account_number = value; }
    }
}
}
```

Here is ADO.NET CODE..

```
      public bool AccountBalanceCheek(AccountBalanceRequest accountNumber)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM 
             Current_Account_Details WHERE Account_Number ='" + 
              accountNumber.Account_Number + "'", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Number", 
                accountNumber.Account_Number);
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return true;

            }

        }
    }
```

Here is Console Application Code..

```
      public static void Balance()
    {
        MyService.HalifaxCurrentAccountServiceClient currentAccount = new MyService.HalifaxCurrentAccountServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IHalifaxCurrentAccou
            ntService");

        MyService.AccountBalanceRequest cs = new MyService.AccountBalanceRequest();


        string AccountNumber;


        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your Account Number--------:");
        AccountNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        cs.Account_Number = AccountNumber;
         MyService.AccountBalanceRequest cs1 = 

     currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(cs);//Error on this line.

                Console.WriteLine("Your Account Number is :" +cs.Account_Number);
                Console.WriteLine("Your Account Type :" + cs.Account_Balance);
                Console.WriteLine("Your Account Account Fee :" + cs.Account_Fee);
                Console.WriteLine("Your Account Balance:" + cs.Account_Balance);
                Console.WriteLine("Your Account Over Draft Limit :" + cs.Over_Draft_Limit);

                Console.Write("--------------------------");
                Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Here is screen shot of out put when i run the application..

[Click here to see the out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNk6g.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `AccountBalanceCheek` is not retrieving data from your DB because it was using `ExecuteNonQuery` and it only returns `bool`

What you can do is:

```
    //change return type from bool to AccountBalanceRequest    
    public AccountBalanceRequest AccountBalanceCheek(AccountBalanceRequest accountNumber)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                //use top 1 since you are only getting one record.
                //let us use string interpolation, if you are working below C#6
                //replace it with your previous value
                var cmd = new SqlCommand($@"SELECT TOP 1
                                                * 
                                            FROM 
                                                Current_Account_Details 
                                            WHERE 
                                                Account_Number ='{accountNumber.Account_Number}'", conn));
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                //use ExecuteReader to execute sql select
                //ExecuteNonQuery is for update, delete, and insert.
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                //read the result of the execute command.
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    //assuming that your property is the same as your table schema. refer to your table schema Current_Account_Details
                   //assuming that your datatype are string... just do the conversion...
                    accountNumber.Account_Balance = reader["Account_Balance"].ToString();
                    accountNumber.Account_Fee = reader["Account_Fee"].ToString();
                    accountNumber.Account_Balance = reader["Account_Balance"].ToString();
                    accountNumber.Over_Draft_Limit = reader["Over_Draft_Limit"].ToString();
                }
                return accountNumber;
            }
        }
```

In your console app code you must use `cs1` to output your values.

```
//previously returns bool, now it returns AccountBalanceRequest
MyService.AccountBalanceRequest cs1 =currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(cs);
//use cs1
Console.WriteLine("Your Account Number is :" +cs1.Account_Number);
Console.WriteLine("Your Account Type :" + cs1.Account_Balance);
Console.WriteLine("Your Account Account Fee :" + cs1.Account_Fee);
Console.WriteLine("Your Account Balance:" + cs1.Account_Balance);
Console.WriteLine("Your Account Over Draft Limit :" + cs1.Over_Draft_Limit);
```

Comment: overwrite it in your `AccountBalanceCheek` method.

Comment: when i replace this code inside AccountBalanceCheek  its showing this following error Can not implicitly convert type object to string ....on this four line accountNumber.Account_Balance = reader["Account_Balance"];
                accountNumber.Account_Fee = reader["Account_Fee"];
                accountNumber.Account_Balance = reader["Account_Balance"];
                accountNumber.Over_Draft_Limit = reader["Over_Draft_Limit"];

Comment: Please cheek my console application out put  as well that what i am trying to achieve  .Thaks

Comment: just added `.ToString()` to convert it to string... you will have to convert the `reader` result to your desire data type

Comment: Thanks . Any changes in console application to call this method ??? or code should remain same ?@Jeric

Comment: I marked it as right answer . Thanks once again your value able time @Jeric Cruz

Comment: one more thing the console application unable to print this string line "Your Account Number is :" and rest of the string